# Magento get the SKU of the first simple product in configurable

Tags: php, magento, foreach

I need to get the SKU for a simple product that is part of a configurable in Magento.

Something along the lines of:

```
if($_product is simple) {
    echo $_product->getSku();
}
elseif($_product is configurable) {
    $simples = $_product-> //Get simple products;

    foreach($simples as $simple) {
        echo $simple->getSku();
    }
}
```

Also how can I check for the product type?

Thanks.

Comment: where you need this on product view page ?

Comment: Could you please provide me with the code that suits Magento 2 version. I am trying to find the SKU of the first simple product of a configurable product in Magento 2. – PKTG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Magento 1**

Did not tested but should work:

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
    if ($product->isSimple()) {
         echo $product->getSku(); 
    } else {
        $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                    ->getUsedProducts(null,$product);
        foreach ($childProducts as $childProduct) {
           echo $childProduct->getSku();
        }
    }
```

You can use:

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == "configurable") 
{
    //Your code here
}

or

if ($product->isConfigurable()) 
{
    //Your code here
}
```

To check type of product.

**Magento 2**

```
/** @var Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $configurableProduct */

$simpleProducts = $configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configurableProduct);

foreach ($simpleProducts as $product) {
    echo "Product Sku: " . $product->getSKU();
}
```

Comment: I get an error using - $product->isSimple()/isConfigurable(). But $product->getTypeId() works. This does exactly what I needed, thanks.

Comment: @Rafał Cz. Could you please provide me with the code that suits Magento 2 version. I am trying to find the SKU of the first simple product of a configurable product in Magento 2.